# continuity in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as:
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n\:\:\:\:\:\:f\left(x\right)=x_i$$
Show that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How to even start? i started by writing down the definition:
Let $\epsilon >0\:$ and some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
We need to find $\delta $ such that if $d\left(x,x_0\right)<\delta $ then $\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)\right|<\epsilon \:$.

($d\left(x,y\right)=||x-y||=\:\sqrt{\sum _{i=1}^n\left(x_i-y_i\right)^2\:}$ )

So i write:
$\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)\right|=\:\left|x_i-x_{0_i}\right|$ but from here i totally don't know how to continue.
Any help will be welcomed.. thanks in advance!

Comment: To begin with, you should write down the meaning of $d(x,x_0) < \delta$.

Comment: What is $x_i$ ?

Comment: @Théophile I think he means the $i$-th coordinate of $x$.

Comment: @kobe But for which $i$? Should $f(x)$ be $f_i(x)$?

Comment: @Théophile it does'nt matter i think..just some coordinate..

Comment: @Théophile I believe $i$ is a fixed integer in $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, and $f$ is the function that sends $x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n) \in \Bbb R^n$ to the $i$th coordinate $x_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $y\in \Bbb R$, setting $\delta = \epsilon$ will make

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |x_i - y_i| = \sqrt{(x_i - y_i)^2} \le \|x - y\| < \epsilon$$

for all $x$ such that $\|x - y\| < \delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are on finite dimensional space then all the norms are equivalent so we can choose for example the sup norm on $\Bbb R^n$ defined by

$$||(x_1,\ldots,x_n)||_\infty=\max_{i}|x_i|$$
and notice that $f$ is linear and we have

$$|f(x)|\le ||x||_\infty$$
so we deduce the desired result.